# How can I output an automatic timer using Handlebars / EmberJs?

Tags: ember.js, timer, ember-data, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I've made a function which works as a timer and executes every second. When I console log the output of the function, it works fine, but it doesn't update graphically. This is my code:

In the model:

```
timer: function(){
   var model = this;
   return setInterval(function(){
      var start = model.get('startTime');
      var end = Date.now();
      var difference = end - start;
      console.log(difference);
      return difference;
 }, 1000);
```

In handlebars:

`{{model.timer}}`

Answer (score 0):

This must be a comment.Unfortunately I can't do that yet.
Where exactly are you getting your 'startTime' from?
I would like to see a fiddle or hopefully a twiddle

Comment: It just gets a timestamp of another date, I would make a fiddle but I don't know how to use it for ember

Comment: Iam guessing this is the effect u are looking for:https://ember-twiddle.com/198e4ac18f1aa9d994f7

Comment: But Iam sure there are more efficient ways to do it

Comment: Any time you reach for `afterRender`, you should consider moving the code to a component instead and using the appropriate [lifecycle hooks](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at something like [ember-cli-clock](https://github.com/jerel/ember-cli-clock). Even if you do not want to use an addon, you can inspect the source code and take some inspiration on how to solve it yourself.

To answer more directly, I would move the code to the component's `init`, and set a property instead of returning:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  timer: 0,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    let start = Date.now();

    setInterval(() => {
      var end = Date.now();
      var difference = end - start;
      console.log(difference);
      this.set('timer', difference);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```